# pacclient.py is not working with IBM Spectrum LSF Application Center Community Edition

Tags: lsf

Installed IBM Spectrum LSF Community Edition with package `lsfsce10.2.0.12-x86_64.tar.gz`

1. Installed IBM Spectrum LSF 10.1 Fix Pack 12
2. Installed IBM Spectrum LSF Application Center 10.2 Fix Pack 12

After installation, when I run paccclient to ping or logon to the cluster, getting `Feature unavailable in this edition` as response.

```
$ ./pacclient.py ping -l https://<IP>:8443/platform
Feature unavailable in this edition.
```

Internally paccclient.py is using following api, I ran the same with curl.

```
$ curl -k https://<IP>:8443/platform/webservice/pacclient/ping/
Feature unavailable in this edition.
```

How can I enable this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Looks that your LSF version does not include this feature. You should upgrade LSF Core to STANDARD edition instead!